# why this batch file starts nothing

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I have a problem with this old program. I before had the linux version who worked well, but I need for some reason the windows version, which never worked. While it is based on java and only the starting script seems to differ, based on what was told by software creator.
At first, I had a problem with

```
ECHO -mode       Wise2 running mode [wing|global|both]
```

which brought "'global' is not a recognized internal command or program".
So I looked a little into it and changed that for string as the pipe | doesn't seem to work well.

But now it simply doesn't start, while before there was a running % and some output files in the end.
I thought of 
 SET SHARKHOME=%~p0
and %~dp0 in place, but no luck.

I changed the direction of the slashes in the classpath hard coded part (\ to / since that's what echoing %sharkhome% gives me back, complete with final slash c:/user/
I had no luck again, but tried to suppress the slash between %sharkhome% and hard coded directories (so %sharkhome%java instead of %sharkhome%/java or %sharkhome%\java) but no luck again.

I am stuck with this. Why doesn't this work, please?

```
@ECHO OFF

REM #############################
REM  SHARKhunt execution script #
REM  Windows version 28/2/06    #
REM #############################

SETLOCAL

REM get SHARKHOME from path of batch file
SET SHARKHOME=%~p0

REM # set classpath
SET CLASSPATH=%SHARKHOME%\java\sharkhunt1.0_win32.jar:%SHARKHOME%\java\jdom.jar:%SHARKHOME%\java\jakarta-regexp-1.2.jar

REM ############################################

REM # default directories
SET TMP=%CD%
SET PROFILES="%SHARKHOME%\priam_06_win32"
SET VER="priam_06"
SET BLASTHOME="%SHARKHOME%\blast"
SET WISEHOME="%SHARKHOME%\wise2"
SET OUTPUT=%CD%


REM # default options
SET EUK=true
SET BLASTCUT=1.0
SET LEEWAY=2000
SET MAXREGIONS=5
SET MODE=both
SET FINALCUT=0.1
SET XMX=2048M

REM ############################################


REM # check user options

IF NOT DEFINED %2 GOTO HELP
IF %1 == "-h" GOTO HELP
IF %1 == "--help" GOTO HELP
IF %1 == "-help" GOTO HELP

:LOOP

IF %1 == "-euk" (
SET EUK="%2"
SHIFT
SHIFT
GOTO LOOP
)
IF %1 == "-blastcut" ( 
SET BLASTCUT="%2"
SHIFT
SHIFT
GOTO LOOP
)
IF %1 == "-leeway" (
SET LEEWAY="%2"
SHIFT
SHIFT
GOTO LOOP
)
IF %1 == "-maxregions" (
SET MAXREGIONS="%2"
SHIFT
SHIFT
GOTO LOOP
)
IF %1 == "-mode" (
SET MODE="%2"
SHIFT
SHIFT
GOTO LOOP
)
IF %1 == "-finalcut" (
SET FINALCUT="%2"
SHIFT
SHIFT
GOTO LOOP
)
IF %1 == "-out" (
SET OUTPUT="%2"
SHIFT
SHIFT
GOTO LOOP
)
IF %1 == "-tmp" (
SET TMP="%2"
SHIFT
SHIFT
GOTO LOOP
)
IF %1 == "--profiles" (
SET PROFILES="%2"
SHIFT
SHIFT
GOTO LOOP
)
IF %1 == "--blasthome" 
SET BLASTHOME="%2"
SHIFT
SHIFT
GOTO LOOP
)
IF %1 == "--wisehome" (
SET WISEHOME="%2"
SHIFT
SHIFT
GOTO LOOP
)
IF %1 == "--Xmx" (
SET XMX="%2"
SHIFT
SHIFT
GOTO LOOP
)

SET DATA=%1
SET GENOME=%2

IF %EUK% == "f" SET EUK=false
IF %EUK% == "F" SET EUK=false
IF %EUK% == "FALSE" SET EUK=false
IF %EUK% == "t" SET EUK=true
IF %EUK% == "T" SET EUK=true
IF %EUK% == "TRUE" SET EUK=true

SET BLASTMAT="%BLASTHOME%\data"

REM # run SharkHunt
START java -Xmx$XMX -cp %CLASSPATH% -Dshark.tempdir=%TMP% -Dshark.eukaryote=%EUK% -Dshark.genomepath=%DATA% -Dshark.profiles=%PROFILES% -Dshark.blasthome=%BLASTHOME% -Dshark.wisehome=%WISEHOME% -Dshark.output=%OUTPUT% -Dshark.maxregions=%MAXREGIONS% -Dshark.wisemode=%MODE% -Dshark.cutoff=%BLASTCUT% -Dshark.maxsig=%FINALCUT% -Dshark.leeway=%LEEWAY% -Dshark.wisemode=%MODE% -Dshark.profiles_version=%VER% sharkhunt.SharkHunt %GENOME%

PAUSE

ENDLOCAL

EXIT

:HELP

ECHO usage: $progname [options] genome_path genome_id
ECHO
ECHO options:
ECHO -euk        Eukaryotic genome [T/F]
ECHO "            (default=%EUK%)"
ECHO -leeway     No. of bases to extract each side of BLAST hit [integer]
ECHO "            (default=%LEEWAY%)"
ECHO -blastcut   Cutoff E-value for initial BLAST search [real]
ECHO "            (default=%BLASTCUT%)"
ECHO -maxregions No. of best BLAST regions to take forward to Wise2 search [integer]
ECHO "            (default=%MAXREGIONS%)"
ECHO -mode       Wise2 running mode [String]
ECHO "            (default=%MODE%)"
ECHO -finalcut   Final E-value cutoff [real]
ECHO "            (default=%FINALCUT%)"
ECHO -tmp        Directory for working files [string]
ECHO "            (default=%TMP%)"
ECHO -out        Output directory [string]
ECHO "            (default=%OUTPUT%)"
ECHO
ECHO advanced options:
ECHO --profiles  Specify profile directory [String]
ECHO "            (default=%PROFILES%)"
ECHO --blasthome Specify BLAST directory [String]
ECHO "            (default=%BLASTHOME%)"
ECHO --wisehome  Specify Wise2 directory [String]
ECHO "            (default=%WISEHOME%)"
ECHO --Xmx       Specify JVM size [String]
ECHO "            (default=%XMX%)"
```

Comment: How are you starting your bat file? Is there an error message? Btw, `|global` can't work because | is an operator in dos so the interpreter tries to execute the command `global` which simply doesn't exist. Changing the direction of the slashes also makes no sense because you are on Windows where `\\` is correct (but `/` also works).

Comment: Change `SET SHARKHOME=%~p0` to `SET SHARKHOME=%~dp0`.

Comment: Thanks for answers. As I said before, I tried to change sharkhome to %~dp0 but it gave no luck. There is no error message and the full .bat file is here. I understood that global could not work but now it doesn't yield nothing apart of the help...

Answer (score 2):

Only some remarks and hints:

- [Escape all `cmd` *poisonous* characters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) using

  - `^` general escape character: `ECHO [wing^|global^|both]`
  - or `"` double quotes as follows:
    `SET "PROFILES=%SHARKHOME%\priam_06_win32"`
    `echo "%PROFILES%"`
- (cosmetic) `echo(` displays an empty line instead of `ECHO is off` message
- use `SET "BLASTMAT=%BLASTHOME%\data"` and then `-Dshark.blasthome="%BLASTHOME%"` rather than `SET BLASTMAT="%BLASTHOME%\data"` and then `-Dshark.blasthome=%BLASTHOME%` (note and think on double quotes position)
- to check whether a parameter was supplied to current script 
  use rather 
  `IF "%~2"=="" GOTO HELP` instead of `IF NOT DEFINED %2 GOTO HELP` as last notation could lead to testing variable `%GOTO%` existence: `if not defined GOTO help`, see `if /?`
- change some tests according to [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) and [`IF` command](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html), for instance `IF /I "%~1" == "-h" GOTO HELP`

A code snippet example:

```
IF /I "%~1" == "-help" GOTO HELP

:LOOP

IF /I "%~1" == "-euk" (
    SET "EUK=%~2"
    SHIFT
    SHIFT
    GOTO LOOP
)
```

Another code snippet example (note that operational [`start` command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) is merely displayed by `echo` for debugging purposes; keep ˙echo˙ until debugged; also note that `""` in `start "" something` is not a mistake):

```
SET "DATA=%~1"
SET "GENOME=%~2"

SET "EUK=true"
IF /I "%EUK%" == "f" SET EUK=false
IF /I "%EUK%" == "FALSE" SET EUK=false

SET "BLASTMAT=%BLASTHOME%\data"

REM # run SharkHunt
echo START "" java -Xmx %XMX% -cp %CLASSPATH% -Dshark.tempdir="%TMP%" -Dshark.eukaryote=%EUK% -Dshark.genomepath=%DATA% -Dshark.profiles=%PROFILES% -Dshark.blasthome=%BLASTHOME% -Dshark.wisehome=%WISEHOME% -Dshark.output=%OUTPUT% -Dshark.maxregions=%MAXREGIONS% -Dshark.wisemode=%MODE% -Dshark.cutoff=%BLASTCUT% -Dshark.maxsig=%FINALCUT% -Dshark.leeway=%LEEWAY% -Dshark.wisemode=%MODE% -Dshark.profiles_version=%VER% sharkhunt.SharkHunt %GENOME%

PAUSE
```

Finally, note that my answer only relates to *batch scripting practices*, not to *java*!

Comment: Thanks. Actually this batch file was not written by me but by the software programmer, so I thought it might only be a small mistake, I will try to correct it according to your recommendations.